# What's the difference between using "deploytool" and Matlab Compiler?

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

What's the function of "deploytool" that makes Java package? Is that different with Matlab Compiler? I want to use Matlab to my Netbeans project.

Answer (score 4):

OK, first of all, you need to know that there are multiple products here, and that the products have changed across versions, as MathWorks collected different features together in different ways.

In R2014b and below, we had:

- MATLAB Compiler: make `.exe` and `.dll` files
- MATLAB Builder JA for Java: make `.jar` files
- MATLAB Builder NE for .NET: make .NET assemblies
- MATLAB Builder EX for Excel: make `.xla` Excel add-in files

In R2015a these products were mixed around, and we have:

- MATLAB Compiler: make `.exe` and `.xla` files
- MATLAB Compiler SDK: make `.dll` and `.jar` files, and .NET assemblies

The Builder and SDK products depend on MATLAB Compiler (i.e. in order to use Builder/SDK products, you also need to have Compiler - and of course also MATLAB itself, and any toolboxes you need).

OK. Now in all cases, in order to actually create the thing you want (`.exe`, `.jar` etc.), you need to use the command `mcc`. This comes with MATLAB Compiler, and if you also have the Builder/SDK products then additional options are enabled (that let you build that product's file type).

If you're comfortable using a rather complex command-line method, `mcc` is fine, and (almost) all the functionality of the product is enabled with it.

But the options to `mcc` can get a bit confusing for some people. So you also have `deploytool`. `deploytool` is a graphical user interface that enables you to specify all the options to `mcc` in a simpler point-and-click way, and then it saves those options into a `.prj` (a deployment project) file. You can pass that project file as a single argument to `mcc` (or you can just press a button within `deploytool`) and it will do the compilation.

There are also some additional options available from within `deploytool` that I think MathWorks have not enabled as direct options to `mcc` - such as the ability to provide an icon for a `.exe` file, and add some comments to it that appear in the "Properties" dialog in Windows. But nothing very important.

Answer (score 1):

[`deploytool`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler/deploytool.html) is a function from the MATLAB Compiler. The MATLAB Compiler allows you to generate stand-alone executables from MATLAB. For Java, you also need the MATLAB Compiler SDK, which is an add-on to MATLAB Compiler. See [Desktop and Web Deployment](https://uk.mathworks.com/solutions/desktop-web-deployment.html) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Is it include in Matlab or I've to buy it separated with Matlab?

Comment: No, it's not included, it's separate. It's also quite expensive as with all code generation/deployment tools.